# Cycle plugin caption with one slide

Tags: jquery, plugins, callback, slider, cycle

I can not get to see the div (`.caption`) if the slider contains only one slide (`image`), while if the slider contains multiple slides you see the correct div (`.caption`) for each slide.

Is there an alternative to `after` property?

Thank you very much for the help!

**Here is the code:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="500" height="500" />
    </div>
</div>


$('#slideshow')
    .after('<div id="products-nav">')
    .cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  2000,
        timeout: 0,
        next:   '#next',
        prev:   '#prev',
        pager:  '#products-nav',
        after:function(curr,next,opts) {
            var index=opts.currSlide;
            $('#caption .caption:visible').fadeOut();
            $('#caption .caption').eq(index).fadeIn();
            tooltip();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the option slideExpr: 'img' (or 'div') to force cycle to understand what is the slide.
Currently, you don't have a list of plural slides, so it can't determine automatically what is the slide !

Here a demo of slideExpr: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/slideExpr.html

Comment: I can not find a solution. :(
The caption is not seen because it is in the property after, but can not find a cycle.